# How to display a sequence of plots successively with some pause in R?

Tags: r, loops, plot

Consider the simple example below:

```
> x <- matrix(NA, 20, 5)
> y <- matrix(NA, 20, 5)
> for (i in 1:5) {
        x[, i] <- rnorm(20)
        y[, i] <- rnorm(20)
}
```

Here, I wanted to examine the scatter plot of each column of `x` and `y`.
Thus, I tried to the following loop:

```
for (j in 1:5) {
        plot(x[, j], y[, j])
}
```

But, as you expect, the result is just `plot(x[, 5], y[, 5])`.

In particular, my goal is to see `plot(x[, 1], y[, 1])` for ten seconds, and then see `plot(x[, 2], y[, 2])` for ten seconds, and so on.

How can I do this work?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution could be

```
for (j in 1:5) {
        plot(x[, j], y[, j])
        Sys.sleep(10)
}
```